# Allow anonymous Authentication based on policy in ASP.NET Core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have a service where retrieving `https://myService.com/data?date={utc.yesterday}` is allowed for anonymous (unauthenticated) users, however in certain circumstances `https://myService.com/data?date={utc.today}` is only allowed for authenticated users.

Basically, an admin needs to approve the preview data before anonymous users can see it. The approval is via another api and is not relevant to this question.

How can I set up an *authorization* policy, which can result in a challenge when our DB indicates this data has not been approved. Is it possible at policy authorization time to enforce authentication?

Answer (score 1):

To exclude the controller from authentication process you can use
the allow anonymous attribute:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public class AnonymousController : ControllerBase
 {
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(config =>
    config.AddPolicy("PolicyName",
      policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireAssertion(context => true) ));
```

Comment: Please add a little explanation what is happening here :)

Comment: Hmh. I was too focused on only one aspect of the question. That is challenging the authorization for unauthorized user.. Because that search got me here.

Answer (score 1):

I currently just worked on doing something similar and was able to implement it using a custom authorization handler.  AllowAnonymous tells aspnet core to ignore Authorize attributes but it also gets rid of a default requirement called DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement.  So I could not use AllowAnonymous but, in my custom policy handler if my criteria was met, I also went ahead and marked the DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement as succeeded too.  It succeeds in allowing an unauthenticated user through when the user meets the authorization requirements and returns a 401 when the requirement fails.

```
[Authorize(Policy = "IsResourceApprovedToView")]
public class MyResourceController : ControllerBase
{
}

public sealed class IsResourceApprovedToViewRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement {}

public sealed class IsResourceApprovedToViewAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<IsResourceApprovedToViewRequirement>
{
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, IsResourceApprovedToViewRequirement requirement)
    {
        // Look up whatever you need with classes injected through handler constructor.  You can use var httpContext = context.Resource as DefaultHttpContext; if you did not specify a resource type to get route data
        if (isApproved)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);

            // Now allow anonymous
            var denyAnonymousUserRequirements = context.PendingRequirements.OfType<DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement>();
            foreach (var denyAnonymousUserRequirement in denyAnonymousUserRequirements)
            {
                context.Succeed(denyAnonymousUserRequirement);
            }
        }
        else
        {
           context.Fail(new AuthorizationFailureReason(this, "Not approved"));
        }
    }
}
```

DI:

```
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler,IsResourceApprovedToViewAuthorizationHandler>(); // Add scoped if you need scoped services injected into your handler - otherwise AddSingleton

services.AddAuthorization(o => o.AddPolicy("IsResourceApprovedToView", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().AddRequirements(new IsResourceApprovedToViewRequirement()).Build()));
```

Answer (score -1):

A similar situation is when a login endpoint can't be performed under some conditions (the system is under maintenance or the browser is not supported).

I created a custom AuthorizationHandler that performs different checks based on the context as well as querying the database and then calls Succeed or Fail on the context object.

```
[Authorize(Policy = nameof(LoginRequirement))]
public class LoginController : ControllerBase
{
}

public sealed class LoginRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement { }

public class LoginAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<LoginRequirement>
{
    private LoginService _service;
    public LoginAuthorizationHandler(LoginService service) {
        _service = service; 
    }

    public override async Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context) {
        if (!context.PendingRequirements.Any(req => req is LoginRequirement)) {
            await base.HandleAsync(context);
            return;
        }

        var httpContext = (HttpContext)context.Resource;
        if (_service.CheckLoginConstraints(httpContext)) {
           var requirement = context.PendingRequirements.First();
           context.Succeed(requirement);
        } else  {
           context.Fail();
        }
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, LoginRequirement requirement)
    {        
        var httpContext = (HttpContext)context.Resource;
        if (_service.CheckLoginConstraints(httpContext)) {
           context.Succeed(requirement);
        } else  {
           context.Fail();
        }
    }
}
```